# Energy of an EM Wave and its temperature and amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy

I'm trying to understand why classical physics fails to explain black body radiation.

I'm confused.

According to Boltzmann, energy calculation for em wave is based on temperature.

According to Maxwell, energy calculation for em wave is based on amplitude.

Are those different kinds of energies? How can we determine the energy of an em wave just taking temperature as a parameter, but not amplitude or frequency??

Comment: Start by reading relevant Wikipedia entries so you understand what the "energy  vs.  XXX"  relationships actually mean.  THen move on to "Ultraviolet Catastrophe"

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell is talking about a *single* wave.  Boltzmann is talking about an *ensemble of many many many many many* such waves.  Boltzmann finds that the *average* energy of an ensemble of waves depends on the temperature of whatever the waves contact, assuming that we've let enough time go by that the measurable properties of the system no longer change with time (equilibrium, temperature the same everywhere).

Same goes for any other property you want to consider, for example, the distribution of energy with wavelength (black body curve).

Comment: Indeed! For example you can't define the temperature for a single atom. Temperature is an emergent property of an ensemble.

Answer (score 0):

M. Planck started to explain black-body radiation by the relation predicted with classical statistical mechanics (with continous energy equi-partition to every degree of freedom of the system). This was [Wien's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_approximation) which indeed was accurate for high frequencies but divergent for low frequencies.

Then Planck decided to account for a *quantized* energy (or treat as a series of harmonic oscillators), which by the *then* statistical arguments was **not** justified, and managed to find a relation ([Planck's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law)) which correctly described the [black-body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbody) and was in accord to the original Wien Law in the area the latter was correct.

Now the whole point is why did the *then* statistical mechanics thought this was not a justifiable argument (in fact if one takes into account that a finitely bounded system can have such a propety the rest follows, since it is a physical argument of bounded energy of a bounded system). This was a start of what was to become Quantum Mechanics.